# How to split a column in two and display in two separate columns base on the conditions?

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a select query which will split a column values into two and display it in two separate columns. I want to do this without a function.

> Example:- I have a value in COL1 as "Rating":-Justification". Now I
>   want to split the column value and display Rating and Justification in
>   different columns.

Thanks for your responses. Let me clear any doubts if there are any. I dont want to user a user defined function. The rating column contains values given below plus the separator and justification. (Agree, Disagree, Strongly Disagree) If the column contails Strongly Disagree then that column will contain separator(:-) and justification else not. AND I am usinf sybase.

Comment: "Without a function" is strictly not possible, you need to process the column somehow. I propose you name your database software and version and show some examples of your data and desired output.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter assuming that user doesn't want a user defined function, it's possible.

Comment: @aF: Assuming that the sky is blue, it isn't green. The `left()` and `right()` you use in your answer *are* functions.

Comment: @user968880: Which RDBMS (Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, etc) are you using? They each handle strings slightly differently, so this will affect the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that without a function you mean a user defined function and doing it from memory, it could be something like this:

```
select left(COL1, charindex(':-', COL1)),
       right(COL1, len(COL1) - charindex(':-', COL1) - 1)
```

Comment: Yes. This may be useful but the occurence of ":-" is also not gauranteed. What can be done in that case?

Comment: @user968880: You need to give us more information - specifically, how is the rating separated from the justification? Is there always a space between them? Is there always a space or comma or colon between them? Is rating always a single character value?

Comment: @user968880 if you don't know what is splitting is impossible to do.